# Zend are view variable available inside view helpers?

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, helper

I am wondering if Zend view variables are available in my view helper class without passing them in directly as parameters

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As all view helpers have reference to the view in their `$view` property, the answer is yes.

What you won't know from the helper side is which properties are available. It would be better to pass any required properties to the helper at call or construction time.

Comment: They are there, but if you will use them in your helper it will be very bad helper, as it will violate one of the base principles -- decoupling.

Comment: How do you pass variables to a view helper when you call it?

Answer (score 1):

well you can access `$view` form inside the view helper , i will give an example : 
in the example below you can set and get view vars

```
<?php

class App_View_Helper_Job extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    public function setView(Zend_View_Interface $view) {
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function job() {
           $this->view->var1 = "testing var1 ";
           $this->view->var2 = $this->view->var1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `setView()` is implemented in `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract`, so you do not need to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should know one thing:
view helper's view instance is the one set on helper instantiation It is not updated on view cloning. So you can't say for sure which one you're using if called from partial for example.

Comment: Thats not quite correct. If you implement `setView()` it will receive the actual View-Object before the helper is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I set the view instance in registry and get it from helper the view variables stays. Here is a code snippet I used in my social engine project

```
$view = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_View');
/*
 * Check data available and set it to local variable
 */
if(isset($view->localeTranslations[$key]))
{
   $translate = $view->localeTranslations[$key];
}
```